# Box-shadow being cut off for floating boxes next to each other

Tags: html, css, z-index

The box-shadow of a floating div is cut off by it's right neighbour, but not on the left side.

I played with z-index and overflow: visible but it did not work.

HTML:

```
<div class="doc-page"></div>
<div class="doc-page active"></div>
<div class="doc-page"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.doc-page {
    float: left;
    width: 141px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}
.active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
}
```

Result:
[image: Shadow is cut off]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/au5Lv/1/

Comment: In order for `z-index` to work, the relevant div **must** have `position: absolute;`, `position: fixed;`, or `position: relative;` applied: http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/au5Lv/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`z-index` is still the answer, but you can only apply `z-index` on an element with `position:relative`, or `position:absolute`.

So apply `position:relative` to all of your elements, and then apply the `z-index` to the active one.

Comment: +1 for explaining well instead of just providing code.

Comment: `position: fixed;` also works, consider adding it to your answer for a +1.

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aniruddha153/HKj9P/

HTML:

```
<div class="doc-page"></div>
<div class="doc-page active"></div>
<div class="doc-page"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.doc-page {
    float: left;
    width: 141px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
.active {
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
}
```

Comment: By making the doc-page div at z-index:0 AND giving a higher z-index for the upper lying divs, you can always ensure it stays at the back.

If you found my solution useful, kindly click accept (tick) for my answer.

Comment: `z-index:9999` bad coding practice. `z-index: 1` should do it.

Comment: @Xarcell - Yes. I agree with you. But just for example to make him understand I used it. Also I am trying to keep that div above all, in case he has many other divs with slightly higher z-index values.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `z-index` value; When using z-index value `position` have to defined as well.

```
.active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}
```

Here is working Demo http://jsbin.com/keyilono/1/